Excluding dependencies from bundle (NextJS & Turbopack)
I am using package in my NextJS which includes modules for React Native that need to be excluded. As part of a migration to move to Turbopack from Webpack, I need to find a way to exclude these packages at build time. However, I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to do this. In Webpack excluding dependencies is done by adding package names to an array called externals but Turbopack does not have this.
Below is my current Webpack externals code in my Next.config.mts file;
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.externals.push('pino-pretty', 'lokijs', 'encoding');
        return config;
    }

The only thing I can think of using for Turbopack is resolveAlias and using empty modules like this;
    // mock.js
    export default () => {};

    ...

    // next.config.mjs
    experimental: {
        turbo: {
            resolveAlias: {
                'pino-pretty': path.resolve(__dirname, './mock.js'),
                lokijs: path.resolve(__dirname, './mock.js'),
                encoding: path.resolve(__dirname, './mock.js'),
            },
        },
    },

This appears to work, but it feels wrong. Is there a better way to handle this?
